# need help to understand error : unhashable type 'set' mean error, how to change to unmutable

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, set, mutable

Hi anyone can help me understand how to begin troubleshooting this? what does the unhashable type 'set' mean

```
                    vocabulary, _ = list(zip(*count_pairs))
                    vocabulary = list(vocabulary)
     45             full_token_and_id = zip(vocabulary, range(len(vocabulary)))
---> 46             self.full_token_to_id = dict(full_token_and_id)
     47 
     48             self.token_to_id = dict((k, self.full_token_to_id[k]) for k in list(self.full_token_to_id.keys())[:max_vocabulary_size])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: If you want to use a `set` as a key to a dictionary it needs to be a `frozenset` so that it's immutable. Otherwise values could be added to the `set` without the `dict` knowing it had changed and it would mess up the ordering of items in the `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you give mutable object as key of your dict. Try to use unmutable object in key of your dictionary.

Comment: How to change the key to unmutable